# Shall it be `verification_uri` instead of `verification_url` in the Device Authorization response

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

The spec says `verification_uri`
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8628#section-3.2
And all other IdP supports device flow follows the spec.

But google uses `verification_url`
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device#success-response

Comment: Thanks Simon for this question, I feel less alone. Did you find an answer to your problem? On my side I had to rewrite a function of the lib I'm using to satisfy that oddity, but this is ugly :/

Answer (score 1):

After investigation, this issue has been already opened and answered in the google issue tracker
https://issuetracker.google.com/151238144 OAuth2 Device Grant implementation bug

Let me quote the answer from Google here:

> Hi,
>
> Handle the authorization server response snippet does not support "verification_uri" as a required parameter at this moment. I have created an Internal Feature Request for this. Feel free to post in this thread should you have any additional comments or concerns regarding the issue. I would recommend you to ‘star’ it to ensure that you receive updates about it [1]. You can also adjust notification settings by clicking the gear icon in the top right corner and selecting settings [2].
> I have just created the feature request internally and we don’t have an ETA for the Availability of the feature right now. I would suggest tracking this issue for future updates.